# Is it possible to use Rules to make an action to entities that refers to other with entity reference

Tags: rules, entities

I have type Article that refers one user with entity reference.

article1 refers to user1
article2 refers to user1

I want a Rule to show a message on user profile with all the articles that refer to this user. Is it possible without coding?

Answer (score 2):

Finaly i found the solution to this problem using module [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules).

I create a view of users, i pass the nid as an integer and set a content referencing to the user.

I don't know if there's a better way but this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to perform an action on referenced entities via the drill down syntax `entity:uid:entity`.

However you are asking to display all the articles referenced by a user and that isn't an action. It is context.

What you are looking for is a views list.

Comment: I don´t want de articles written by but referenced by. The author could by another user.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You are still looking for a view. I'll replace written by with referenced (written by is an entity reference field).

Comment: I now it can be done by a view, but I need the Rule that do this although i still need a rule able to use referenced content

Comment: @angoru again, rules perform actions based on events. Views (can) display lists of entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an action called "fetch by property" where you select the entity reference field and provide the uid. That return a list for rules to loop over. You could then display these with a site message.

I think you're looking for views here though. I can't see much benefit from using rules.

Comment: I can´t fetch a node (article) from a Rule launched under event (User account page is viewed) or at least i don't know how.